# JQUERY + PHP + AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing simple program in html which inserts the data into MySQL DB using php script.
But every time I press Save button it redirects me to php page.
I have created Javascript file but its not working for me.
Please help

HTML FILE (index.html)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="demo_insert.php" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    Domain : <input type="text" name="domain"><br />
    Role : <input type="text" name="role"><br />
    <button id="sub">Save</button>
    </form>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>    
</html>
```

php file

```
<?php
         $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
         $db   = mysql_select_db('test');
$name=$_POST['name'];
$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$role=$_POST['role'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO user20015 VALUES ('$name', '$domain', '$email', '$role')";
        if(mysql_query($sql))
         echo "Successfully Inserted";
        else
        echo "Insertion Failed";
?>
```

my_script.js File

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
   });
clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: I have enabled javascript in the browser.

Comment: why do you have two jquery libraries ?

Comment: Why don't you have a <body> element? You need to include your script at the end of the body (once you add the tags) and/or use a document ready handler.

Comment: I tried with body also but it doesn't work and I thought 1.8.1 may not work so added one more

Comment: You should use SQL statements with care. You can use prepared statements like so (check the w3schools tutorials): http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp I usually handle these events with Ajax where I output some data on success or on error. Makes my life a bit easier. If interested, You can check the Ajax API here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
```

with

```
$("#myForm").serializeArray(),
```

As this method "Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values."

```js
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) {
  /* prevent default form submission */
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serializeArray(), function(info){
    $("#result").html(info);
    /* reset form fields to defaults */
    form.reset();
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="demo_insert.php" method="post">
   Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    Domain : <input type="text" name="domain"><br />
    Role : <input type="text" name="role"><br />
    <button type="submit" id="sub">Save</button>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: This also gives the same output. it redirects me to another page

Comment: it redirects you to demo_insert.php after submit right?

Comment: May you share the code(JS + HTML) you are using in jsfiddle or some where else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106233/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-mr-x).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because `$("#myForm").attr("action")` returns a relative URL. Please try with `$("#myForm").prop("action")`. 
And do never include two jQuery libs. Remove the old one. Could cause other problems.

//edit: 
You need a document ready function in your js file. Replace the content with this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click( function() {
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
                 $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                 function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
           });
        clearInput();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
      return false;
    });

});

function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a 
$( document ).ready(function() {
   /*CODE HERE*/
}); wrapped around your content of the javascript file? Your jQuery code is not executed.

Comment: no where should I put this function and what content should I fill in it?

Comment: place it at the beginning of your js file and put all the content that was in it to the /*CODE HERE*/ place.

Comment: For further reading abour the document ready function: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$role=$_POST['role'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO user20015 VALUES ('$name', '$domain', '$email', '$role')";
        if(mysql_query($sql))
```

SQL injection detected. Please remove this, using PDO for example, in order to bind parameters and avoiding one of the biggest mistake ever.

For your issue, try to bind events on the document.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function() { return false; });
```

That's a better practice, and avoid some "bind on not loaded html" issues, that may be yours here.

You may do as well for the click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub', function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
   });
clearInput();
});
```

Comment: with $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function() { return false; }); when I click on submit button it doesn't performs any action

Comment: Yes, because it successfully stops the submit propagation, so we're good. Now, just apply the same logic to the click events, and all should be fine.

Comment: Let him just use a document ready function of jQuery so he could bind all events like he did in his original post...

Comment: @SimonKraus Bad idea. Binding events on document is more reliable, because the document is available as soon as the $document.ready applies. THEN it works even if content is added AFTER the bind. $document.ready should be used only to start javascript which only be executed on the document loading (ajax and so on) not to bind events.

Comment: can you guys please tell me what exactly should I put in which while? As I am getting confused now...

Comment: But this is common practice. You will not see a complete js app with all events bound to the document very often in the wild.. i updated my answer so you can just copy the js code to your file.

Comment: I just edited my answer. @SimonKraus : yes, because most of the JS app are "old fashioned way", or just need to trigger some specific logic (ajax calls in order to load content and so on). But binding events on document is the preferred way if you don't have too much events.

Comment: Now when I click on submit it empties all the text fields then it redirects me to .php page

Comment: Mh. Yes, that's what clearInput() does : it clears all the input fields. Check your console about errors too; if some javascript errors happen, event handlers won't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
    $(function(){//dom has loaded
 $("button#sub").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /// prevent the default click event
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
             $("#myForm").serializeArray(),
             function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
             clearInput();//clear the data AFTER the ajax was triggered
       });

    });

    function clearInput() {
        $("#myForm input").each( function() {
           $(this).val('');
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: same issue it redirects to php page

Comment: you removed `$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false;
});`?